# Visual Basic - Create an application to pick a number

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hye,
I'm new with Visual Basic and i had a few problems.
I've create a new Windows Forms Application in Visual Basic. Using one TextBox and two Button. The TextBox for displaying the number. One button for Generate and another one for Help.

1. I want to create a simple application that will pick one of the listed number instead of generating it.

   Example :
   Each time I click on the Generate button, it will pick either 14412GG or TE921W or 13123SA only. The number will appear in the TextBox.
2. Evertime i click on Help button, a windows will pop-up with help messages. Multiple line messages.

   ```
   Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       **This is for Generate button**
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
       **This is for Help button**
   End Sub

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       **This is to display the number**
   End Sub
   End Class
   ```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Save those 3 values in an arrayList, create a Random class.

```
private static ArrayList values1 = new ArrayList{"14412GG","TE921W","13123SA"};
Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.Next(values1.Count);
(string)values1[r]
```

Display the string when Generate button clicks.

```
TextBoxVariable.Text = (string)values1[r];
```

Use Messagebox.Show to display the help message.

```
MessageBox.Show(""Help message line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Help message line2";");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need :

```
    'Button 1
Dim pool As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        Dim cc As New Random
        Dim count = 0
        While count <= 6
            textbox1.text = cc.Next(0, pool.Length)



 'button2
msgbox("message line1" + vbnewline + "message line2.")
```

i hope it be useful to you .